# Smoothness of $\iint \limits_{A(x,y)} \, s\cdot t \:ds \,dt$ in dependence of the integration area $A(x,y) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $A: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, where $A(x,y)$ is a convex area for every $x,y$.

I'm interested in the function $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $F(x,y) = \iint  \limits_{A(x,y)} \, s\cdot t \:ds \,dt$.

Is there any property of $A$ from that we could conclude the smoothness of $F$?
For example, if $A(x,y)$ is a polygon and its vertices move smoothly when changing $(x,y)$, then $F$ is smooth? What would be a formal argument for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to answer your question is to rewrite the double integral as a line integral, using Green's Theorem. For example,
$$\iint_{A(x,y)}st\,ds\,dt = \frac12\int_{\partial A(x,y)} s^2t\,dt\,.$$
If you can represent the curve $\partial A(x,y)$ as a finite union of piecewise-smooth curves (in your example, you're going to have line segments joining smoothly-varying vertices), then this line integral will be a smooth function of $(x,y)$.